# Plugging cord into laptop or wall question closed as NARQ

Tags: support, specific-question

I asked [if it matters which side of the power cord you plug in first](https://superuser.com/questions/418779/laptop-should-one-plug-the-ac-first-or-to-the-laptop-first) but it got closed. The reason, "not a real question".

I don't know how it was "unclear".

Comment: Probably because you didn't supply any evidence that it matters. As Breakthrough mentions in the comments, there doesn't really seem to be a question, because it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

I understand the question may have been closed in great haste, but you need to understand that this question isn't constructive for the reasons I posted in the comment [Ivo Flipse](https://meta.superuser.com/users/1548/ivo-flipse) pointed out.  Any modern computer manufacturer has to build their components up to the specification and licensing of the country they're sold in.  And indeed, all of North America ([FCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCC_Declaration_of_Conformity)/[CSA](http://www.csa-international.org/certification_marks/)) and Europe ([CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking)) do have standards in place for this sort of thing, **especially** for devices which are going to be plugged into the wall.

It doesn't matter which end you plug into what first, because it doesn't have to - mostly because the devices have to be up to the regulatory safety standards before they can be sold.

---

Actually, one last thing just came to mind.  All of this goes out the window if you buy cheap, third-party, unlicensed laptop chargers (or any other device chargers for that matter).  This is a huge safety concern ([ref](http://www.arcfn.com/2012/03/inside-cheap-phone-charger-and-why-you.html)), for both your device, and more importantly, *for you*.  However, even toching on this manner addresses an entirely different question:  *Is my charger **safe** to use?*  And even in this case, the order you plug what into what is still irrelevant.

---

Aside: Since there are possible safety risks involved, does anyone think it's worth editing the question or an answer so the above three paragraphs can be seen by other users finding this question?

Comment: Yes. And in general, suppressing knowledge is a bad idea. Please re-open the question.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I've simply edited the original question (prefixed with "Moderator Edit") to include the relevant information from above.

Comment: I asked about it in the mod room, and well, its not really a moderator edit if you arn't a mod, and that's not how edits should be used IMO.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek fair enough; just to clarify, I wrote "Moderator" so other people visiting the question wouldn't get confused or assume the OP had written that text.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things really

1. This is a hypothethical question - What would be the *practical* implications of this? What even got this question asked? Does your computer malfunction or not work in any way as a concequence of this? I haven't even heard folk-myths to this effect (unlike say with audio where you want to turn stuff off in a certain order to prevent damage)
2. If it was an issue it would be in the manual - which by the way, if it was, might help solve 1. If it isn't its not a concern, without other factors in play.

I think this should remain closed cause its a "an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?” as per the FAQ/